# ionic loading small local image is slow

Tags: javascript, angular, image, ionic-framework

So this is really odd.

I have a few SVG files that are local in the project with a path `/assets/images/image.svg`

Now the maximum size of these images is **25kb** however whenever I open a page that contains an image the loading still doesn't appear instantly which means that is a little flicker before the image is loaded.

Has anyone experienced this before and know if there are any way to optimize the loading? It seems excessive to include some sort of library to handle images of this size?

Comment: are you using `ion-img` tag? if yes try only `img` tag.

Comment: @NajamusSaqib i am using ion-img how is img faster?

Comment: I don't know actual issue, but `ion-img` have some problems. try `img` tag.

Comment: @MarcRasmussen using img doesn't support lazy-loading, which is important if you have lots of images.

Comment: @MarcRasmussen it is a bug of ionic 3 and if you are using ionic 4 and bug still there please report.. to ionic git... here is the reference.... https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11326